# Historical model does not allow deletion in reverting django data migration

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'v two models

```
class A(models.Model):
    index = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    audio = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    x = models.SmallIntegerField()
    y = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and

```
class B(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    index = models.SmallIntegerField()
    audio = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I made a data migration that initializes model A objects (every object also creates B objects with it and every created B also creates C objects with it.)
Here is the migration:

```
from django.db import migrations


def create_as(apps, schema_editor):
    A = apps.get_model('super_app', 'A')
    B = apps.get_model('super_app', 'B')
    C = apps.get_model('super_app', 'C')  # C has FK referencing B
    # Some logic here that creates instances of A (also creates B and C)

def delete_as(apps, schema_editor):
    A = apps.get_model('super_app', 'A')
    A.objects.all().delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('super_app', '00xx_the_very_previous_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_as, delete_as)
    ]
```

The migrations is applied forward successfully.. but when I try to revert back the migration (Which should call `delete_as`) I'm always having this error:

`ValueError: Cannot query "B object (757)": Must be "B" instance.`

I've been trying and digging but no clue why this happens!
Note: The type of models in migrations are historical models (`__fake__.{MODEL}`) I tried to use the latest state of the model by doing:

```
def delete_as(apps, schema_editor):
    A = apps.get_model('super_app', 'A')
    from django.apps import apps  # FIXME. This gives latest models state.
    B = apps.get_model('super_app', 'B')
    B.objects.all().delete()
    A.objects.all().delete()
```

And it worked without problems and I could revert the migration!! But, according to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#historical-models), this should not be used.

Any ideas about why this happens?

Comment: Did you had any luck solving this issue?

Comment: @Guilherme Nope, not yet :(